# Communication between two React form components with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Assume that you have a form like below to add a new person:

[image]

In this example, when you select a country from the populated select list, the city select element will be populated with options based on the selected country. This form page (`PersonCreationForm`) consists of below components:

- CountrySelectionForm
- CitySelectionForm

The question here is this: how should I communicate the selection from `CountrySelectionForm` component to `CitySelectionForm` component? I have a few options in mind but I am not sure what would be the perefered way to handle this in Redux world:

- Inside the `PersonCreationForm` component by just hooking up the `onCountrySelected` prop of `CountrySelectionForm` and passing the result to `CitySelectionForm` through its `country` prop. No need to go through Redux for this communication. However, changing the `country` prop triggers a change in `CitySelectionForm` to get cities based on selected country from Redux store.
- On country selection, `PersonCreationForm` component dispatches the action indicating which country is selected. Based on that, `PersonCreationForm` gets notified and passes the result to `CitySelectionForm` through is `country` prop. That triggers a change in `CitySelectionForm` to get cities based on selected country from Redux store.
- On country selection, `PersonCreationForm` component dispatches the action indicating which country is selected. Based on that, `CitySelectionForm` gets notified. That triggers a change in `CitySelectionForm` to get cities based on selected country from Redux store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend you to use [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) for such situations. In your case it would be something like this:

```
render() {
  const {fields, handleSubmit} = this.props
  return (   
    <form>
      <CountrySelectInput {...fields.country}/>
      <CitySelectInput {...field.city} country={fields.country.value}/>
      <input type="text" {...fields.name}/>
      <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit(this.addHandler)}>Add</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

To make this work you should process "value" and "onChange" props in your ContrySelectInput and CitySelectInput components. Like normal inputs do.

Redux-form module will significantly simplify your life with the forms. You can do something like that with a clean redux (option 1 in your list). And it will be still right.

Comment: thanks! an unrelated question: what is `{...fields.country}` doing there? is it another way to pass props? I assume this is a spread operator in ES6, right?

Comment: Redux-form container provides `fields` prop to the component. And `fields.country` is actually an object with such properties as `value`, `onChange`, `error` and so on. And `{...fields.country}` just adds all these properties to the component.

Comment: I see, so `<CountrySelectInput {...fields.country}/>` is equivalent to `<CountrySelectInput value={fields.country.value} onChange={fields.country.onChange} error={fields.country.error}/>`, correct?

Comment: Also, I don't see on your example how `CitySelectInput` would know about a change on the country selection. Can you explain that?

Comment: Yes, it's just another to specify properties for the react component.

Comment: My fault. I've corrected the code sample to pass the country prop to the city input component.

Comment: OK, I see that how now. However, in this approach, both `CitySelectInput` and `CountrySelectInput` knows about `redux-form`, is that right? or is it just the outer wiring component cares out `redux-form`?

Comment: No, you should just process the properties `value` and `onChange` by them. So that redux form could track its values. Only PersonCreationForm should deal with redux form.

Comment: Please see my answer, I posted a bit more code for the connections

Answer (score 1):

there is a **possible** way to determine which option you can use:

**IF you DON'T need** to share the data across the app, and components have the same parent, **then** you can do it with local state. Therefore it saves your time, because you dont need to write actions, reducer's code, etc. and you dont need any abstractions.

**IF you need** to share the data across the app, **then** you can use redux stuff

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar using `react-redux` and `redux-form`. You could do something like this:

AddUserForm.js:

```
render() {
    const {fields, handleSubmit} = this.props
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <CountrySelect {...fields.country} />
            <CitySelect {...fields.city} />
        </form>
    )
}
```

CountrySelect.js:

```
import { updateCities } from 'actions'
...
render() {
    const {handleChange, ...rest} = this.props
    return (
        <select {...rest} onChange={handleChange}>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
            ...
        </select>
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        handleChange: (event) => {
            let countryId = event.target.value
            dispatch(updateCities(countryId))
            return countryId
        }
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CountrySelect)
```

CitySelect.js:

```
render() {
    const {cities, ...rest} = this.props
    return (
        <select {...rest}>
            {cities.map(city => {
                return (
                    <option key={city} value={city}>{city}</option>
                )
            })}
        </select>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        cities: state.cities
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CitySelect)
```

actions.js:

The function `updateCities` will set redux `state.cities` to an array that looks like this:

```
state.cities = [
    'Los Angeles',
    'New York',
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Redux for this use-case. You can use the `PersonCreationForm` component as a wrapper with an internal state.

The two selects `CountrySelectionForm` and `CitySelectionForm` have to receive by props a dedicated handler which perform a `setState()` when they are triggered inside children components on the 'onSelect' event.

The `CitySelectionForm` component will receive by props the value of `CountrySelectionForm`thanks to the state managed by the smart component `PersonCreationForm`.